# Straightforward way to make a schematic plot

Tags: plot, draw

I am relatively new to LaTeX. I would like to create the following sort of schematic plot. What would be the most straightforward way?  Should I use [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en), [`pgfplots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en), or something else?  Can you help me get started with the following?

[image: plot]

Here is a MWE with the packages that I am using for my thesis:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
%\usepackage{pgf}?
%\usepackage{pgfplots}?
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Ragone plot}
  \label{fig:ragone}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure TikZ:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
                
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Stealth,
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt},
  N/.style = {font=\sffamily, align=left},
every label/.style = {label distance = 0pt, N}
                        ]
\draw[<->]  (0,5) |-  (6,0)
    node[pos=0.25, N, above,rotate=90]     {energy density (Wh/kg) \\ {[range]}}
    node[pos=0.75, N, below]    {power density (Wh/kg)\\ {[possible second line]}};                     
%
\node[dot, label=right:battery\\{[possible second line]}] at (1,3) {};
\node[dot, label=right:supper capacitor\\{[possible second line]}] at (3,1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Ragone plot}
\label{fig:ragone}
    \end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

produce:

[image]